# How to make a bunch of pages in NodeJS with ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to make a website for my game community.

This is the code I'm using:

```
db.query('SELECT * from users', function(err, rows, fields){
  for (var i in rows){
    ws.get('/inv/' + rows[i].STEAM_ID, function(rew, res){
    res.send("Inventory of " + rows[i].name + ",br. " + rows[i].inv)
  }
 }
}
```

My issue is that it only generates one inventory page. One for the last user in the users array.

I need it to generate one for everyone.

Comment: Calling `res.send()` sends the response and ends the request. At that point you can't do anything more for this request. It looks like you're trying to **write multiple lines to a single page**, not send multiple pages (which is impossible because you can only send one response). If you're trying to write more than one line to a single page, then build up the response string inside the loop, and pass the response string to `response.send(responseString)` after the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should switch it around:

```
app.get('/inv/:user', function(req, res) {
    var query = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = ' + req.params.user;
    db.query(query, function(err, data){
        res.send('Inventory of ' + data[0].name + ': ' + data[0].inv);
    });
});
```

This way, when you request a page `/inv/[userid]` it will run a query to get the data for that user, and send it back to the browser. Which I assume is what you wanted to do.

*Note: never just put user input data into your query, always escape it first.*